# How to disable menu options when transitioning between pages in ViewPager?

Tags: android

When transitioning between pages, each fragment page shares the same menu options. The menu option contains button which launches an activity. That activity is highly dependent on the information the current page item shows.

I noticed that when I change the view such that, the next page is almost shown on the screen (not fully transitioned) and I select the option for that item, the options shows the data from the previous item. I think this is because, he transition between pages was not fully complete. This is kind of confusing for my users. There could be people who swipe faster and press the option button. I noticed then when swiping between fragments and then suddenly press the menu option. The options shows the data from the previously active page.

If I could only hide the menu options, and only show it when the page is fully transitioned, I believe I can solve this problem. Or else, maybe I am doing something wrong which could have averted this in the first place?

I am using FragmentStatePagerAdapter.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html) and when the [`onPageScrollStateChanged`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html#onPageScrollStateChanged(int)) event is triggered check to see the state of the scroll if is idle then the page is in view and active (allow user to press the menu button), if is in another state then lock/hide the menu buttons.

Comment: I am already using my custom made FragmentStatePagerAdapter. I can't override that method from there. I am scrambling for alternatives

Comment: You have a ViewPager associated with the FragmentStatePagerAdapter, you should use the ViewPager `setOnPageChangeListener` to set that listener, you don't need to change your FragmentStatePagerAdapter

Answer (score 1):

When the button is clicked check ViewPagers current item -
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#getCurrentItem()

```
YourObject object = yourList.get(yourViewPager.getCurrentItem());
```

Comment: I am not so sure how this will solve my problem? What is the point of getting the current item? This is quite sparse. I am so sorry.

Comment: When you click the button you want to get the information from the last seen item from viewpager. And I am sure you have given some list to the pageAdapter, so now when the user clicks the button, you are querying the list, that you gave to ViewPager with the last seen position.

Comment: Thanks! But I think I am more inclined on just setting up flags. as the previous user suggested. But I will surely try your suggestion.For now, for me trying to detect what was previously selected is a little bit of too much code for me which will put me to risk of over-engineering my fragments and activities.

Comment: Add your layout and adapter and adapter creation to the question, and I will show you how to implement this with your code

Answer (score 1):

I think I was able to solve my problem. I created an interface on my fragment which the hosting activity has to implement:

```
public interface OnOptionsMenuEnabledListener{ public boolean onOptionsMenuEnabledListener(); }
```

The hosting activity will just return a flag indicating if the menu is enabled.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsMenuEnabledListener()
{
    return mOptionsEnabled;
}
```

And set the flag via  `ViewPager.onPageScrollStateChanged (int state)`:

```
@Override 
public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) 
{   
    switch(state)
    {
        case ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE:
            mOptionsEnabled = true;
            break;

        case ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING:
            mOptionsEnabled = false;
            break;

        case ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING:
            mOptionsEnabled = true;
            break;
    }
}
```

Every time the option is being selected during screen transition, I call the interface method to communicate to me what the status of the flag:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    boolean enable = true;

    if(mOnOptionsMenuEnabledListener != null)
    {
        enable = mOnOptionsMenuEnabledListener.onOptionsMenuEnabledListener();
    }

    if(enable)
    {
      ...
      // select your menu items
    }
    return true;
}
```

So in this approach, the menu is still there (which is a big plus). But the option menu doesn't react until it settles down on a particular page.

With this I no longer encounter the problem.

I hope this help someone in the future!
Cheers!